# TypeScript Error "'err' is of type 'unknown'" in Firebase Authentication and Redirection Issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to firebase and this is my first fullstack project, currently working on a user authentication system. I'm encountering an error message stating "'err' is of type 'unknown'". Altough the code is working fine but this error is showing in my code editor. I'm not sure how to handle this error.

Additionally, after a successful login, the user is not being redirected to the "/overview" route as expected. The relevant code is as follows:

```
const signIn = async () => {
    try {
      await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      console.log(auth.currentUser?.email);

      <Navigate to="/overview" />;
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.code === "auth/invalid-login-credentials") {
        try {
          await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
          console.log(auth.currentUser?.email);

          <Navigate to="/overview" />;
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

I've read many firebase realted threads on stackoverflow and one on github which was using a regex and was for flutter and too complicated. I was hoping, someone could help me figure out how to handle this error and ensure the user is redirected after login or sign up.

Comment: As for your navigation issue, use the `useNavigation()` hook.

Comment: @Phil thanks, both of my issues have been resolved. 
had to do `if ((err as FirebaseError).code === "auth/invalid-login-credentials")` to solve the error. and the navigation issue is solved too.

Comment: In modern versions of TypeScript, the catch error variable is always typed as "unknown".  You have to check/cast it to what you think it might be.